# network driver adapter problems

Tags: networking, drivers

i installed windows 7 ultimate. every time i start my computer i'm getting the x mark in network when trouble shooting it says "***intel network adapter is experiencing hardware or driver related problems***". im installing network drivers every time i tsart my pc. please tell me what to do.
when i install the drivers and trouble shoot again it says no problem and my adapter driver is upto date.

Comment: What is your network adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

There can be a lot of factors because of which you are getting this message. First be sure that the operating system that you downloaded is original and not some pirated version that you get on torrents. Those are generally tweaked by hackers that makes a lot of system programs to not work efficiently. Next thing to see would be your network adapter. Call a computer technician to look into your network interface card. And lastly the device drivers should be compatible with the hardware. If the problem still persists then it is beyond my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

First try to update the driver, use Driver Pack Suite from www.drp.su
If the problem persist,boot a live linux and test the internet.
The drivers are the main reasons for hating Windows/Microsoft stupid solutions.